# How to set proxy for AJAX calls in a simple react app?

Tags: php, reactjs, proxy, npm-start

I created simple react app as described in https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html and now want to make AJAX calls to the webserver (with PHP). To make it working with development server at **localhost:3000** I am trying to set up proxy in **package.json**

```
"proxy": {
  "/abc": {
    "target": "http://web.local/app/path/public/abc",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately app answers with default **index.html** content. How to make proxy working when requesting **/abc** path?

Is there any way to test and debug proxy? When I try to open http://localhost:3000/abc I can see

```
[HPM] POST /abc/abc -> http://web.local/app/path/public/abc
```

in console. But there is no messages when I'm loading app and request is sent from the app. (I tried **fetch** and **axios** calls.)

When I build app and run it on web server, all works fine.

**EDIT:**
Response Headers for the **axios** ajax call:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 143
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2018 17:44:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

For **fetch**:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 165
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: /abc/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2018 17:58:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

And

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
ETag: W/"649-W8GnY7MkgPFg6/GXObpRHPnVDeU"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2018 17:58:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Can you post the response headers of the POST request? It's probably a CORS violation.

Comment: Added, at the moment it returns 404 also web server is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved issue. My php files were located in **public/** dir of the app (to have them included in build). And it is accessible from development web server as static content. Now proxy checks if file exists in **public/** and delivers it if possible. And if there is no such file, then rules are applied and it tries to fetch data from specified URL.

So I moved all php related files to other location and needed data are delivered from web server through proxy as inteded just with

```
  "proxy": "http://web.local/app/path/static"
```

in **package.json**.

Also I had to add separate command to copy content of this dir to **build/** and add it to build process.